# search not returning results on document content

Tags: 2010, search

I've noticed that the search does not return expected results when searching on the content of a document, but does return the expected results if I search using the title of the document.

To test I uploaded a document, ran an incremental crawl, opened the document, copied a line of the text and pasted it into the search box.  This did not return any results that included the uploaded document.  I then took a copy of the documents title from the title column and pasted it into the search box.  This returned the document as expected.

Can anyone explain why this happens

Comment: Have you seen and tried http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15562/sharepoint-search-not-indexing-contents-of-document-libraries ?

Comment: @RobertLindgren thanks for that.  I think my problem is different.  I can see that the documents have been crawled in the log.  It just seems if i search on text within that crawled document its not returned